# custom font for textview in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the font of a `TextView` in my `ArrayAdapter`. The font `chantelli_antiqua.ttf` is in the assets folder.

<strike>Here is my Java code:</strike>

```
listItemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MenuItem>(this, R.layout.listitem, menuItems);

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "chantelli_antiqua.ttf");  
TextView v = (TextView)listItemAdapter.getView(0, null, null);
v.setTypeface(font);
```

xml for the listitem layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
/>
```

I'm quite sure the problem lies with the `Adapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method. I just don't really understand what to pass as variables and tried `null`. But this doesn't do what I would like it to.

How to change the font of the `TextView` in the `Adapter` to the custom font?

## Update

According to Pixie's suggestion I created a `MenuItemAdapter` which extends `ArrayAdapter<MenuItem>`:

```
public class MenuItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem>
{
    private Typeface font;

    public MenuItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MenuItem> objects) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "chantelli_antiqua.ttf"); 
    }

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        ((TextView)view).setTypeface(font);
        return super.getView(position, view, viewGroup);
    }
}
```

And changed my java code to:

```
listItemAdapter = new MenuItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, menuItems);
```

But now my app crashes after the `onCreate` of the `ListActivity`, but before hitting the breakpoint in `getView(...)`, I haven't been able to figure out yet why. Any suggestion?

## Update2

Changed the code for getView(...) to:

```
@Override  
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
 View v = super.getView(position, view, viewGroup);
 ((TextView)v).setTypeface(font);
 return v;
}
```

and this works. :)

Comment: [Applying custom Font using Layouts](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/07/applying-custom-font-in-entire-android.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call the `getView()` method of your adapter. The `ListView` does this for you. You have to extend the `ArrayAdapter` class and override the `getView()` method instead. In this method you have to inflate a new view or re-use `convertView` and set the typeface for this view.

Comment: This sounds like a promising answer but didn't get me there yet completely. Please see my updated Question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in `return super.getView(position, view, viewGroup);` at the end of getView() method.
I think it should be like this

```
 @Override  
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    TextView tv = ((TextView)view).setTypeface(font);
    tv.setText(<String> getItem());
    return tv;
}
```

please note this code is example I didn't try it now but I made custom arrayAdapter before and it was something like that.
Here is a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html) describing how to create custom arrayAdapter.

Comment: +1 True, this is the solution. I managed to figure it out as well, unfortunately I didn't read your answer before. thanks anyway.

Comment: I noticed that a call to the super is needed as well though, otherwise view is null in my case.

Comment: yes you should check if(view == null) at the beginning of your getView method and if true then you should call findViewById() to get your view and then continue normally

Comment: this didn't work in my case at all, and getItem() needs a position value