# Setting font on ListActivity in Android

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to set a custom font on a list activity in Android. I can successfully do it once an item gets clicked, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View listItemView,
        int position, long id) {

        int childCount = listView.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            TextView c = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i);
            c.setTypeface(mTypeFace);
        }
```

However, before the item is clicked, assigning a font has no impact:

```
    //
    // Create the adapter to display the choice list
    //
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_custom,
            mAppState.mAnswerArray) {
    };


    /* attach the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    ListView v = getListView();


    int childCount = v.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        TextView c = (TextView) v.getChildAt(i);
        c.setTypeface(mTypeFace);
    }
```

Debugging show that in the initial setup, the ListView v has zero children, despite the fact they show up in the GUI and mAnswerArray has the children.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried calling invalidate() either on the ListView or on the TextViews after setting the typeface?

Comment: Just tried it - no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the viewBinder and override the setViewValue in your adapter, like so:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex == 7){
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setTypeface(gotham_book);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but it looks like the ArrayAdapter doesn't support the setViewBinder method. That's apparently for connecting database fields to the adaptor views.

Comment: oops! check out this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911198/custom-font-for-textview-in-arrayadapter

Comment: Thanks, that link was the ticket